# AWSDateTime to readable format

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have AWSDateTime like `2019-05-03T18:18:13.683Z` that I want to just use in a user friendly format such as `5/3/2019`.

Is there some kind of method that just formats it like `item.createdAt.abrakadabra()` or would I need to make some crazy javascript function to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate, but here it goes anyway:

```js
var awsDate = new Date('2019-05-03T18:18:13.683Z')
var yourDateStr = awsDate.toLocaleDateString();

console.log('yourDateStr', yourDateStr)
```

This will get you going.

Comment: VanillaJS should be sufficient.

Comment: LOL. Good one :)

Comment: found it there!

Answer (score 0):

hey look at all this love! ya I just wrote this js function before I saw the response and got some good practice in the process. I'm gonna look at the toLocalDateString thing but here is this for people since I made it

```
formatDate(date){
  if(typeof date !== typeof null){
    const month = (date.slice(5,6) === '0') ? date.slice(6, 7) : date.slice(5, 7);
    const day = (date.slice(8,9) === '0') ? date.slice(9, 10) : date.slice(8, 10);
    const year = date.slice(0, 4)
    return month.concat("/").concat(day).concat("/").concat(year)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah your way was easy and also your right this has prob been answered a bunch. this was what I went with(my date is in a string)

```
formatDate(date){
    var dateobj = new Date(date);
    return dateobj.toLocaleDateString()
}
```